# How to resolve the confliction between "<resources" tag and "<context:component-scan.." tag for Spring MVC showcase project

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm currently working on a  Spring MVC project and have some issue with using `"<MVC:resource "`tag of SpringMVC to load static resource. So I downloaded the springMVC showcase project and did some change on it to check this tag.

Since my project is a simple one, seems to me the two tags for "conversionservice" is not necessary.

However after I removed this two tag, something wired happend. 
If I have both the tag for static resources `"<resources mapping="/resources/.."`  and the `"<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.samples.mvc" />"` tag (in controllers.xml) configged, then I cann't access any uri that anotated on controllers- it returns a 404 not found error. if I comment out the resource mapping tag, then those controllers works fine.

Anyone have ever experience this situation? Any idea how to get around that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->


<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService">
        <argument-resolvers>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.samples.mvc.data.custom.CustomArgumentResolver"/>
        </argument-resolvers>
    </annotation-driven>

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources/ directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

<!-- Only needed because we install custom converters to support the examples in the org.springframewok.samples.mvc.convert package -->
    <beans:bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="formatters">
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.samples.mvc.convert.MaskFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory" />
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


    <!-- Imports user-defined @Controller beans that process client requests -->
    <beans:import resource="controllers.xml" />

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Finally after added the tag     "<context:annotation-config/>" everything works fine now. Still not sure the reason behind. just record it here so someone has the same problem can save their time.

Comment: you need to show us your controller mappings.

Answer (score 2):

`<context:annotation-config/>` just don't work on Spring 3.1.0, but `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` just works, I referenced [this post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?94571-Controller-not-found-by-context-component-scan)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and what I did is to remove the "**" in the resource tag.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue - [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34471043/spring-mvc-default-servlet-handler-configuration-blocking-jstl-view)

You can either use  `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` or provide handler mapping yourself with order of higher precedence -

```
<bean id="annotationUrlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>
<bean id="annotationMethodHandlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
```